# how to find a specific value in json response (python)

Tags: json

```
response = requests.post(url,params=params, headers=headers)
s = json.loads(response.content)
print(s)
```

```
{'success': 1, 'status_code': 200, 'response': {'0': {'campaign_id': 33571, 
'clicks': '65', 'views': '1677', 'ctr': 0, 'price': 0.0155, 'cpm': 0.4943, 
'ad_id': 135837, 'position': 1, 'good_type': 'Товар или услуга', 'volume': 
 32.696, 'is_yours': True}, '1': {'campaign_id': 0, 'clicks': 0, 'views': 0, 'ctr': 0, 'price': 0, 'cpm': 0.4935, 'ad_id': 0, 'position': 2, 'good_type': 'Товар или услуга', 'volume': 24.722, 'is_yours': False}}, 'msgs': {'error': [], 'success': [], 'warning': [], 'info': []}}

I need to find ad_id which equal '135837' in this array and print 'cpm' and
'position', trying to do this but got an invalid syntax
```

```
for i in s['response']:
if i['ad_id'] == '135837'
print(i['cpm'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over dict values, not dict indexes. For this purpose use items() method, which returns key and value of every dict element.
Also you should compare the value not with string ("135837"), but with integer (135837), as it exists in the json string.

```
for key, value in s["response"].items():
   if value["ad_id"] == 135837:
      print(value["cpm"])
```